# Python remove dictionary items when a value of a specific key is duplicate

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of this form:

```
nodes = [ 
    {"name": n1, "nodename": nod1, "nodetype": t1, "nodeip": nip1},
    {"name": n2, "nodename": nod2, "nodetype": t2, "nodeip": nip2},
    {"name": n3, "nodename": nod3, "nodetype": t1, "nodeip": nip3},
    {"name": n4, "nodename": nod4, "nodetype": t3, "nodeip": nip4},
    {"name": n5, "nodename": nod5, "nodetype": t2, "nodeip": nip5},
]
```

and I want to remove all keys that have a duplicate value in "nodetype" such as:

```
uniq_nodes_per_type = [ 
    {"name": n1, "nodename": nod1, "nodetype": t1, "nodeip": nip1},
    {"name": n2, "nodename": nod2, "nodetype": t2, "nodeip": nip2},
    {"name": n4, "nodename": nod4, "nodetype": t3, "nodeip": nip4},
]
```

It is not important which of n1,n3 or n2,n5 will be selected.
How can I get the above result?

I have tried to iterate the values like that:

```
seen = set()
uniq_nodes_per_type = {}
for node in node_list.items():
    nodetype = node["nodetype"]
    if nodetype not in seen:
        seen.add(nodetype)
        uniq_nodes.update(node)
```

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. Your example is hence invalid, please check again

Comment: list of dict ? maybe

Comment: Yes, I updated the dict, it was wrong.

Comment: What's the expected output ? which of the duplicate dicts you want to keep

Comment: It is not important which of n1,n3 or n2,n5 will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input was meant to be a list of dicts:

```
nodes = [ 
    {"name": "n1", "nodename": "nod1", "nodetype": "t1", "nodeip": "nip1"},
    {"name": "n2", "nodename": "nod2", "nodetype": "t2", "nodeip": "nip2"},
    {"name": "n3", "nodename": "nod3", "nodetype": "t1", "nodeip": "nip3"},
    {"name": "n4", "nodename": "nod4", "nodetype": "t3", "nodeip": "nip4"},
    {"name": "n5", "nodename": "nod5", "nodetype": "t2", "nodeip": "nip5"},
]
```

Building a dictionary based on `nodetype` keys will remove duplicates:

```
nodetype_dict = {x["nodetype"]: x for x in nodes}

sorted(nodetype_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x["nodetype"])
[{'name': 'n3', 'nodeip': 'nip3', 'nodename': 'nod3', 'nodetype': 't1'},
 {'name': 'n5', 'nodeip': 'nip5', 'nodename': 'nod5', 'nodetype': 't2'},
 {'name': 'n4', 'nodeip': 'nip4', 'nodename': 'nod4', 'nodetype': 't3'}]
```